# Add block to checkout onepage review

Tags: magento-1.8

I wanna insert a block in the review part of the checkout process, but it will not work. I did the following in my local.xml file:

```
<checkout_onepage_review>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="myblock" name="myblock" as="myblock" template="mytemplate.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

if i include the block in the base layout checkout.xml it works... Is the reference root correct? Can't find any mistake...

Comment: add this code in review.phtml <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('myblock'); ?>

Comment: hmm ithink that must be in /checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml. But i already did that. That's not the mistake!

Comment: yes.but check answer also

Comment: put local.xml code?

Answer (score 3):

You could always use a different reference. I am not sure where you want to include it etc but most things that add blocks to this use.

```
<reference name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after">
```

For example `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/authorizenet.xml` adds some form after the items.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I figured I'd insert my ¢2.

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

- Enable System logging and Exceptions logging in `System > Configuration`, `Advanced > Developer > Log Settings`, `Enabled > Yes`, and check your Exceptions log file, typically at `/var/log/exception.log`. This will check to see if your module's block type is invalid, and where you should look to double-check your block core file.
- Checking the PHP `error_log` file in your Magento root directory for potential code errors in your block template file.
- Check to make sure the reference to `root` (`<reference name="root">`) in your Checkout Layout XML file `/app/design/frontend/THEME/PACKAGE/layout/checkout.xml` hasn't been changed or somehow overwritten.

I had this issue, and I solved it by checking these three things.

Answer (score 0):

your block class invalid.

Magento `default block type` is `core/template`.

used  `type="core/template"` instead of  `type="myblock"`

Comment: The block i want to include there is a custom block. It's just an example. The type is correct, because as i mentioned before, it works if i include it in the base checkout.xml file.